# Really "basic" sorry... I Can't see how to create a simple EXE in VB.net. I Can't even see how to publish my app simply

Tags: vb.net

I have used VB5 extensively and it created exe files - easy to deploy without having to install much else. I will be really disappointed if my recent use of "modern" .net (I moved over for extra features) means I can't even create the age old simple exe file... What a pain! Hope I'm wrong...

Comment: I mean standalone EXE without a setup. (But in fact I can't even figure out how to make a setup either, to tell the truth...)

Comment: Vb 5 had/has a "make executeable" in the menu options. Where's it gone?

Comment: Sorry if my comment seems to be rude, but have you followed any kind of basic tutorial before jumping on the Visual Studio/Net Framework toolset? It seems that you are lacking the basic understanding of how this toolset works. Remember that you are not just changing language but also IDE and libraries.

Comment: lots of tutorials etc explain the various build options. It's a totally different toolset, you can't really expect it to just work exactly the same way and all the buttons be in the same place. There's a lot more you can do, but that also makes it a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a project an exe file will appear by default in either the bin/Debug/ or bin/Release/ directory (depending on the build configuration) under your project every time you compile it.

It's not a "native" exe file though, so it will require the .NET Framework to be installed to run, however most relevant machines should already have at least some version installed.

Comment: Awesome... That's the answer I was looking for.. I did look around quite a bit for tutorials such as typing the question in Google, and only more advanced pages came up. Thanks again Matti